# Getting data from div to modal via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have PHP generated div's that have some data from database. every one of them have unique ID. I need to get data from selected div (I have this coded) and through it's ID it's supposed to put data from this div to modal.

MODAL:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit-modal-label">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="form-horizontal" id="edit-form">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Zamknij"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="add-modal-label"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Edytuj Pracownika</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="add-firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imie</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-firstname" name="imie" placeholder="Imie" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="add-nazwisko" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nazwisko</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-nazwisko" name="nazwisko" placeholder="Nazwisko" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="add-pesel" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefon</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-pesel" name="telefon" placeholder="Telefon" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="g" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Godzina rozpoczęcia</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="g" name="od" placeholder="00:00" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="t" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Godzina zakończenia</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="t" name="do" placeholder="00:00" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="b" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Płeć</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="b" name="plec" placeholder="Mężczyzna" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="d" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Typ Konta</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="d" name="typ" placeholder="Lekarz" required>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zamknij</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-user-edit"></i> Edytuj Pracownika</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

function that calls modal out:

```
function edit(){
    $('#edit-modal').modal('show');
}
```

one of divs:

```
<div class="panel panel-kol" mid="4"><div class="panel-body profile white">
  <div class="profile-image"><img src="../assets/images/users/rec.svg" alt="Osoba"></div>
  <div class="profile-data">
    <div class="profile-data-name" style="font-weight: bold;">Krzysztof Marczewski</div>
    <div class="profile-data-title">Recepcjonista</div>
  </div>
</div>                                
<div class="panel-body">                                    
  <div class="contact-info text-center" style="margin-top: -20px;">
    <p><small>Telefon komórkowy</small><br>997998999</p>
    <p><small>Od - Do</small></p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="00:00:12">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="00:00:19">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
      </div>            
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

"mid" is unique ID assigned to every div generated by PHP. I just need to take data from already generated div into modal

ss:
[image]

ss v2.

[image]

Comment: mid is invalid attribute or id or html5 data-* atrributes...

Comment: which data need transfer from the panel to modal ?

Comment: Every single input from panel

Comment: How is `edit()` function called?

Comment: <button class="btn btn-block" onClick="edit();"><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span> Edit</button>

Comment: u have multiple panels with unique mid and data ?

Comment: Yup, sir. That's exactly what I have there

Comment: Just a clarification, you have to replace all the modal html with html from a div with certain mid?

Comment: Yes, I am attaching screenshot to post to clarify everything

Comment: Screenshot is attached. The thing is to create a modal that loads data from selected div so I can later send them to PHP script. I just dont want users to write data from scratch since it's edit they dont want to change everything but just a part of data. That's why I need to have data loaded into modal that will execute PHP script

Comment: panel have data for all inputs in modal ?

Comment: Ehmm yes. That's right

Comment: I just need to get all data from div with specific ID and then push this data into modal's input

Comment: can i add some tags or classes to data in panel ?

Comment: You can do whatever is needed for you to make it work

Comment: watch my answer below, i cant insert link...copy jsfiddle and open...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

watch this, if i understood correct...

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
function edit(){
            $('#edit-modal').modal('show');
        }
function insertData(mid){
  var panel = $('.panel[data-mid="'+mid+'"]'),
      fullName = panel.find('.full-name').text(),
      arrName = fullName.split(" "),
      modal = $('#edit-modal');
    
  modal.find('#add-firstname').val(arrName[0]);
  modal.find('#add-nazwisko').val(arrName[1]);
  modal.find('#add-pesel').val(panel.find('.phone').text());
  modal.find('#g').val(panel.find('.start-time').val());
  modal.find('#t').val(panel.find('.end-time').val());
}
    
    edit();
    insertData(4);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="edit-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit-modal-label">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="edit-form">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Zamknij"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="add-modal-label"><i class="fa fa-user-md"></i> Edytuj Pracownika</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="add-firstname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Imie</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-firstname" name="imie" placeholder="Imie" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="add-nazwisko" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nazwisko</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-nazwisko" name="nazwisko" placeholder="Nazwisko" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="add-pesel" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Telefon</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="add-pesel" name="telefon" placeholder="Telefon" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="g" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Godzina rozpoczęcia</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="g" name="od" placeholder="00:00" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="t" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Godzina zakończenia</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="t" name="do" placeholder="00:00" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="b" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Płeć</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="b" name="plec" placeholder="Mężczyzna" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="d" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Typ Konta</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="d" name="typ" placeholder="Lekarz" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Zamknij</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-user-edit"></i> Edytuj Pracownika</button>
              </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
  <div class="panel panel-kol" data-mid="4"><div class="panel-body profile white">
                                <div class="profile-image"><img src="../assets/images/users/rec.svg" alt="Osoba"></div>
                                <div class="profile-data">
                                    <div class="profile-data-name full-name" style="font-weight: bold;">Krzysztof Marczewski</div>

                                    <div class="profile-data-title">Recepcjonista</div>
                               </div>
                            </div>                                
                            <div class="panel-body">                                    
                                <div class="contact-info text-center" style="margin-top: -20px;">
                <p><small>Telefon komórkowy</small><br><span class="phone">997998999</span></p>
                                    <p><small>Od - Do</small></p>
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control start-time" value="00:00:12">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control end-time" value="00:00:19">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                     <div class="col-md-2"></div>
                                </div>            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate your help very much!

Comment: Probably not a best solution to select each field's value manually.

Answer (score 1):

To assign inputs from modal to data from a div, I would suggest to set an `data-*` attribute for each node with the information we need. For example:

```
<div class="profile-data-name" style="font-weight: bold;">
  <span data-imie="firstname">Krzysztof</span> 
  <span data-nazwisko="lastname">Marczewski</span>
```

It should be equal with the `name` attribute for the associated input from the modal.

And afterwards, in `edit()` function, you should iterate through all the inputs and set their value with associated data:

```
function edit(mid){
  var inputs = $('#edit-modal').find('.modal-body').find('input);
  inputs.forEach(function(input) {
    $(input)
      .val($("div[mid='" + mid + "']")
      .find('[data-name="' + $(input).attr('name') + '"]).text())
  })
  $('#edit-modal').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: That's really not what I was hoping to get. Take a look at the picture. There is data that is not editable. If I display this data into modal it's still undeditable. The point is to get values from div so I get like a lot of variables. Like name, surname etc. And then I post them somehow into mnodal I have created already that's also attached to post

Comment: So in div let's say I have a text with class "name" that's not an input and then I want to take this NAME and place it into modal into specific input that's only into modal not into div itself

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer in a while. But please, be more specific in the question next time.

Comment: I have been trying to be as specific as It is conceivably possible. I am sorry

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if i understood wrong what the problem is. Try `var divValue = $( "div[mid='4']" ).val()` and push it into modal :) [Here](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)'s jQuery documentation for atribute equals select.

Comment: I assume you understood wrongly. My main concern was how to push it into modal, and divValue will be empty since the inputs inside div' are my target